# Why does TypeScript allow me to use an `any' in an interface requiring a string?

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript allow me to put a variable typed as `any` in an object typed as an interface which requires a string? Is there any way I can enable more strict type enforcement?

This code regrettably compiles:

```
const x: any = {};
const y: any = [];
const z: any = 10;

interface AnInterface {
  x: string;
  y: string;
  z: string;
}

const t: AnInterface = { x, y, z };
```

In the real-world situation that causes me this problem, I'm want to load an `any` object, which is a row returned from an Oracle DB query, into an object conforming to a more strict interface.

Comment: Don't use any... Any is meant to be dynamic. You probably want to use `unknown` instead of `any`

Comment: That's the whole point of any: a variable of typed any is not type-checked, and can contain any value. In short, you're back to JavaScript, and TypeScript will let you do anything you want with a variable of type any, trusting you're doing something correct. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

Comment: But it's not written by me – it's from a set of DefinitelyTyped typings. The object in question is a row in a database query result set which is inherently untyped

Comment: Types from DefinitelyTyped are made by the same people like you and me, so they can also make poor choices. Or it is just the best that can be done, to use `any`, because no one knows which type it will be. Very legit for  database management programs.

Comment: And why would TypeScript change the rules of any because you've not written it by yourself? If it's of type any, it's of type any, and the rules pertaining to any apply. So you can assign any to a variable of type string, because it **could** be a string, and TypeScript trusts you, and assumes you know it's indeed a string.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. Is there any way I can turn off this leniency and require that only strictly typed variables be assigned to the variables I want to protect, requiring an explicit cast in order to bypass it?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can structure your code so that the usage of any is encapsulated in specific classes dealing with the database rows, and exposing methods returning type-safe objects.

Comment: @JBNizet right, that's the strategy I went for. Thanks for your input. (Really wish the language would support better protection here though)

Answer (score 0):

Because `any` can be *any* type, including `string`.